# How do I change a tooltip at runtime?

Tags: office365, tooltip, office-js, office-addins, ribbonx

The tooltip of a ribbon button is set in the manifest.xml file, which is a static file, but is it somehow possible to change the text in the tooltip of a command button in the ribbon at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide anything for that. There is no callback provided for the [Supertip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/supertip?view=powerpoint-js-preview) element, you need to specify them in the manifest. For example:

```
<Supertip>
    <Title resid="funcReadSuperTipTitle" />
    <Description resid="funcReadSuperTipDescription" />
</Supertip>
```

The `resid` attribute can be no more than 32 characters and must be set to the value of the id attribute of a `<String>` element in the `<LongStrings>` element in the `Resources` element.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.